# php convert all links to absolute urls

Tags: php, url, curl, hyperlink, web-crawler

I am writing a website crawler in php and I already have code that can extract all links from a site.
A problem: sites use a combination of absolute and relative urls. 
Examples (http replaced with hxxp as I can't post hyperlinks):

hxxp://site.com/

site.com

site.com/index.php

hxxp://site.com/hello/index.php

/hello/index.php

hxxp://site2.com/index.php

site2.com/index.php

I have no control over the links (if they are absolute/relative), but I do need to follow them. I need to convert all these links into absolute URLs. How do I do this in php?

Comment: What are you using to parse html and find the links? Your library might already have a way to resolve relative urls.

Comment: I am using my own html link extracting function. I am not using any library except from curl and php functions.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a start

```
// Your crawler was sent to this page.
$url = 'http://example.com/page';

// Example of a relative link of the page above.
$relative = '/hello/index.php';

// Parse the URL the crawler was sent to.
$url = parse_url($url);

if(FALSE === filter_var($relative, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{
    // If the link isn't a valid URL then assume it's relative and
    // construct an absolute URL.
    print $url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'].'/'.ltrim($relative, '/');
}
```

Have a look into the [http_build_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php) method as another way of creating an absolute anchor.

Comment: a relative could be also $relative = '../hello/index.php';