# Change relative urls to absolute in an html document using DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am using curl to get some html pages in strings, but I have a problem when i display it , it doesn't show the images nor the css ,let say
the data have this

want to get modified to

thanks!
I want it to modify the whole html page ...

Comment: <img src='images/test.jpg' /> to <img src='http://test.com/images/test.jpg'/>

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wget` with the `-k` option](https://superuser.com/questions/80060/make-wget-convert-html-links-to-relative-after-download-if-k-wasnt-specified). Or just see the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268556/php-convert-all-links-to-absolute-urls).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that links to images and stylesheets are relative instead of absolute, so your browser doesn't know the real origin of the page when displaying it. A quick fix would be to add

```
<base href="http://domain.com" />
```

(with the real originating domain) in the head of your page prior to displaying it.